# Can I install phpMyAdmin on its own to access a seperate database?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set up access to a mysql database for a separate user. Of course that's not a problem, easily set up. Separate username and password.

The problem however is with my host, with mySQL databases, you have one master login to the PHPmyAdmin, which is automated login through cPanel. There seems to be no way to login to the myPHPAdmin interface with the separate username and password, only accessing PHPmyAdmin. The only way to access the PHPmyAdmin was through the cPanel, with the ONE username and password, which would then be able to see and edit all databases on my hosting account, which I don't want. I accepted this at the time when I was researching, and put the project on hold.

A few weeks ago I was installing a new wordpress installation (unrelated project), and found an old link to a wordpress plugin which enabled me to do exactly what I want to do! (Link here : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin). It uses the mySQL database information in the config.php file of the wordpess install to display PHPmyAdmin. It limits the display to the database the wordpress install uses.

My thoughts were, if this can be done by a wordpress plugin, then why not some sort of stand alone php page? I don't have enough php knowledge to hack up the plugin, but I would have thought there was something already like this out there, I just don't know what it's called or how to find it.

The support team from HostGator suggested using a desktop application to access the database, but the cPanel requires the ip address of anything that wants to access it remotely, and we don't have one (in our house). By using the wordpress installation, it uses "localhost" as the server address, removing the ip problem.

Please do edit and tag if I have explained things in a poor way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install a standalone version of phpMYAdmin yourself on your hostgator domain. Download the PHP applcation from http://www.phpmyadmin.net/.

In CPanel you can create separate users that only have access to certain databases. effectively restricting what databases they can edit. I don't believe that you can make restriction on uses at the table level thou.

Or Search Google for phpmyadmin alternatives.

One of my faviorte alternatives is [SQL buddy](http://www.sqlbuddy.com/). Its a true upload and go PHP application. it works really well and i have used it many times in the past when phpMYAdmin  wasn't already installed. Its not as good as phpmyadmin but still pretty good.

There is also [aerosql](http://www.burlaca.com/aerosql/), I heard good things about but never used.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I thought you could probably do that, but wasn't sure if my host would restrict me from doing so. Will give as correct answer after I have done it.

Answer (score 1):

The standalone PHP is phpMyAdmin itself. You can [download](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) and install it yourself and configure it however you like. HostGator has just set one up with settings they like for you, but nothing prevents you from doing it too.